# YQL and Spotify

Tags: spotify, yql

I'm trying to build an app for Spotify that uses YQL for data extraction. I have problem with setting up permissions. I have added url-s that I'm using for html but I couldn't even start app after adding permissions...

Html itself without Spotify returns the results so problem is not in page itself

Here is the manifest entry I used for permissions:

```
"RequiredPermissions": [ 
    "http://developer.yahoo.com"],
    "http://developer.yahoo.com", 
    "http://*.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?", 
    "http://*.datatables.org/alltables.env", 

 ]
```

Could you help me? Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a bracket in the middle of the entry, after the first developer.spotify.com list item.

Also, I'm not totally sure you need the question mark after yql.

Try something like this:

```
"RequiredPermissions": [ 
    "http://developer.yahoo.com/",
    "http://*.yahooapis.com/v1/public/", 
    "http://*.datatables.org/", 

]
```

Answer (score 1):

Pompa answer is right, you've got a typo.

Plus, as stated by Spotify docs (but generally speaking it's a CORS policy), you only need to pass needed hostnames in the `RequiredPermissions` list, so this should be enough:

```
"RequiredPermissions": [
    "http://*.yahoo.com",
    "http://*.yahooapis.com",
    "http://*.datatables.org",
]
```